# Word 2007 allows unwanted styles in Word 2003 protected documents

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2003

We use Word 2003 documents that have their styles locked down (via "Protect Document"). We have a strict list of styles because we later map the documents to XML.

When we open our existing documents (2003) with Word 2007, extra "Built In" styles appear as options.

[image]

Why would Word 2007 be designed to insert these ridiculous styles as options in a document that is supposed to be "Protected"?

Any ideas how to fix this? Could I possibly use a macro to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

It's because the Protection does not lock-***in*** your styles only, it simply locks-***out*** other ones (the ones you didn't choose). So, in Word 2003 you lock out styles like Table 1, Heading 1, etc. leaving only the ones you want remaining.

In Word 2007/2010, there are new styles that are part of the Quick Styles templates (like Bibliography, Intense Emphasis, etc.). You can find all Quick Styles templates in *C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\1033\QuickStyles* (assuming you're using English, which is 1033) and *C:\Documents and Settings(userID)\Application Data\Microsoft\QuickStyles* (if the user has saved their own Quick Styles). It's a bit stupid, but because these were not locked out in Word 2003 explicitly, they are available to your Word 2003 document/template in Word 2007.

A macro may work here because your `ActiveDocument` inherits Quick Styles in Word 2007 as its own. But you'd have to specifically name each of your own styles in a For/Next loop to add it to allow-in for restricted styles.

Another way to do this is to open one of these templates and copy the styles via the Organizer into a a new Word document in Word 2007, save that document as a Word 2003 document (.doc) and then in Word 2003 add these styles to the Normal.dot template. Then, open my Word 2003 document and disallow all of these newly added styles during restriction.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Otaku. The problem is we already have thousands of Word 2003 documents in circulation. Is there a way to configure our users machine's to remove the styles after Word 2007 is intalled? Can we modify the QuickStyles templates?

Comment: I tried modifying the styles in the QuickStyles directory but it did not effect how they appeared when opening up a word 2003 document in compatability mode.

Comment: @joe: are you looking to remove all instances of QuickStyles from Word 2007, or just for specific Word 2003 documents that you've deployed? If the later, does the doc have an identifier, like a custom property?

Comment: I would settle for either. For some reason no matter what .dotx or .dotm files I change. Word 2003 documents still seem to open with these default styles. If I could even change their color it would help to show they are invalid.